# secrets doesn't exist with podman version 1.6.4

Tags: podman

I have a rhel7 host and I'm testing using podman on this host instead of docker. I've found out that `yum install podman` using the OS upstream installs old version of podman 1.6.4 because it looks like that new podman versions have dependencies that are not supported with centos/rhel 7. I tried to create secrets using podman with this 1.6.4 version but I get an error that there is no such a command. so my question is does podman support for creating secrets came with later versions than the 1.6.4 I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/new-podman-secrets-command), Podman implemented secrets support in version 3.1.0.